# In Android Studio how to batch set flavor dependencies？

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies

Suppose I have lots of flavors:

```
android
{
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 { ... }
        flavor2 { ... }
        flavor3 { ... }
        flavor4 { ... }
        flavor5 { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of set the dependencies of the flavors one by one:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/flavor1/libs')
    flavor2Compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/flavor2/libs')
    flavor3Compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/flavor3/libs')
    flavor4Compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/flavor4/libs')
    flavor5Compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/flavor5/libs')
    ...
}
```

I want a simple way to loop over such as the pseudocode：

```
dependencies {
    all {
        entry ->
          compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/' + entry.name + '/libs')
    }
}
```

Is this achievable with build.gradle? If so how to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out. Just loop the `productFlavors` in the `dependencies` and then call `add` method manually:

```
dependencies {
    android.productFlavors.each {
        flavor ->
            add(flavor.name + 'Compile', fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'src/' + flavor.name + '/libs'))
    }
}
```